# Hide all products from specific category in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to hide all products from a single category in woocommerce, but I would like to have them on the shop page, or in the search results.

Is there a way to exclude all product showing from a specific category? On the category page settings i have options to show subcategories, products, both.

But I want neither of them to show. Is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that I wrote and tested, and it works fine.

Use this to add a dropdown in your Add/Edit Product category page:

```
//Product Cat Edit page
function add_show_hide_select_product_cat($term) {

    //getting term ID
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field.
    $show_hide_products = get_term_meta($term_id, 'show_hide_products', true);
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="show_hide_products"><?php _e('Show/Hide products', 'woocommerce'); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <select name="show_hide_products" id="show_hide_products">
                <option value="1" <?php selected( $show_hide_products, 1 ); ?>>Show products</option>
                <option value="0" <?php selected( $show_hide_products, 0 ); ?>>Hide products</option>
            </select>
            <p class="description">Show or Hide all products of this category on it's page</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action('product_cat_add_form_fields', 'add_show_hide_select_product_cat', 10, 1);
add_action('product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'add_show_hide_select_product_cat', 10, 1);

// Save extra taxonomy fields callback function.
function save_show_hide_select_product_cat($term_id) {

    $show_hide_products = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'show_hide_products');
    update_term_meta($term_id, 'show_hide_products', $show_hide_products);
}

add_action('edited_product_cat', 'save_show_hide_select_product_cat', 10, 1);
add_action('create_product_cat', 'save_show_hide_select_product_cat', 10, 1);
```

Then here's the code that will hide all the products based on your selection:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query' );
function custom_pre_get_posts_query( $q ) {
    
    if (is_product_category()){
        $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
        $show_hide_products = get_term_meta($term_id, 'show_hide_products', true);
        if ($show_hide_products == 0){
            $tax_query = (array) $q->get( 'tax_query' );
            $tax_query[] = array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => array(17),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            );
            $q->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
        }       
    }
    
    return $q;
}
```

Put both of them in your functions.php file and it should work fine.

It'll give you a selection in your edit category screen to show/hide products of that category on that category page like this:

[image: Category option]

I've made it the way that by default it'll show all products when you first insert this code so nothing is hampered and suddenly your products don't hide for all categories.

If you hide them explicitly in any category then they get hidden.

Let me know if this worked for your website too.

Comment: Unfortunately not. This plugin hides the product from search, and from the shop page too.

Comment: The plugin mentions that it hides the products from the category pages only and not from the search and shop.

Comment: tested, and it hides products from the search.

Comment: I've updated the answer with fully working code that I tested on my local. Do let me know if the same works for you.